# GHUnit/GHTestApp.h: No such file or directory

Tags: xcode, unit-testing

I'm very new to objective-c, xcode, and mac development in general (I
come from a java development background).  I'm attempting to integrate
GHUnit into xcode to write some simple unit tests for an objective-c/
cocoa project I've recently been tasked with.

I've attempted to follow the directions here :
http://gabriel.github.com/gh-unit/_installing.html for:
Installing (Mac OS X)
-- Installing in /Library/Frameworks.
I'm working with xcode 3.1.3 running under Mac OS 10.5.8

I have created the new Target "Tests", and Link Binary With Libraries
shows the GHUnit.Framework.
I've added the GHUnitTestMain.m to the project as the directions
describe.  However, I get "error: GHUnit/GHTestApp.h: No such file or
directory" for the #import

I looked for this header file in the framework and I don't see it
included.  #import  is not causing any errors, and I
DO see this file in the framework directories.

Is the downloaded framework and the GHUnitTestMain.m out-of-synch with
each other?  or have I missed something in the configuration?

As another note, in the directions:
"If your main target is an application, you will need to include these
source files in the Test project manually."
I don't understand what action is required from this statement.  I
have no idea if it's related to my current compilation error.

Thanks for any help in sorting this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you downloaded the OS X version of GHUnit. The github page lists a few downloads for iOS aswell. At the time GHUnit-0.4.26.zip is the latest OS X version.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.

You might add the test class to the main application target. Uncheck the target and then, the error "GHUnit/GHUnit.h file not found" disappeared.

[image]